# Ajax update textarea without button or page refresh

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am trying to create a textarea that automatically updates the database without the need to press a button or refresh the page. After a "keyup" occurs there will be a timer that will countdown for 2 seconds. If no other input is made within those 2 seconds then that the data should be updated in the database. If a input is made the timer will restart.

I've written the ajax code below, it doesn't seem to work.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var timer;
  $('#about').on('keyup', function() {
    var value = this.value;
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
      //do your submit here
      $("#about").submit()
      alert(value);
    }, 2000);
  });
  var about = $('#about').val().trim();
  $.ajax({
    url: "comment.php?customer_id=" + "<?php echo $customer_id; ?>",
    type: 'post',
    data: {
      about: about
    },
    success: function(response) {
      $('#cid').val(response);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
/* This is comment.php */

<?php
session_start();
require_once 'config/config.php';
require_once 'includes/auth_validate.php';

$cid = $_GET['customer_id'];
$about = $_POST['about'];

$sql = ("UPDATE patient_id SET about = ? WHERE id = ?;");

$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "si", $about, $cid);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
?>
```

Comment: Explain what makes you think it does not work. Also what do you see in developers console?

Comment: I'm not understanding the point of doing the submit.  I thought your goal was to perform the ajax after the 2 seconds?  The ajax is outside of that timeout.  The ajax as it is currently written, only executes once, on page load, which is...... odd

Comment: @Taplar that was just an indicator of if the code was working or not

Comment: Ok, so..... why not put the ajax in the timeout and remove the submit?

Comment: @u_mulder i know its not working because when i refresh the page the changes are not made to the database. When I select for the data from the database, it is not updated

Comment: @Taplar could you make that change in the form of an edit or a post, im not sure how to go about that change.

Comment: You literally just move the part that is getting the `about` and performing the ajax call, **into** the timeout

Comment: Also consider changing `keyup` to `input`.  keyup will fire for arrow keys, input only fires if the value changes.  You don't want to perform an update if nothing changed.

Comment: @Taplar i made the change, but i suspect i may be doing it wrong. Could you edit my post or make your own with all the changes you proposed please. Your help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the ajax into the timeout, rather than performing the submit, since you want to update with ajax.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var timer;
  $('#about').on('input', function() {
    var value = this.value;
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
      alert(value);
      $.ajax({
        url: "comment.php?customer_id=" + "<?php echo $customer_id; ?>",
        type: 'post',
        data: {
          about: value
        },
        success: function(response) {
          $('#cid').val(response);
        }
      });
    }, 2000);
  });
});
```

Comment: @James you were 99% there on your own.  I was hoping to coax you past your mental block without an answer, :)